# Calling scp from Python's subprocess not working with filelist \{a,b,c\}

Tags: python, string, bash, subprocess

I want to call a command like

```
scp username@hostname:/dir/to/files/\{a,b,c\} /target/dir
```

from Python to copy many files in one command.
The command works perfectly if entered directly into the shell.

But if I use

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['scp', 'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/\{a,b,c\}',
                      '/target/dir'])
sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)
```

I get the error

```
scp: /dir/to/files/{a,b,c}: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, the backslashes are missing. And if I use double backslashes in the Popen arguments like

```
\\{a,b,c,d\\}
```

I get the error

```
scp: /dir/to/target/\a: No such file or directory
scp: /dir/to/target/\b: No such file or directory
scp: /dir/to/target/\c\: No such file or directory
```

Nothing changes if I use raw strings like `r'\{' + r'\}'`

How can I call the scp command from Python with the correctly escaped curly braces `'\\{a,b,c\\}'`?

Comment: note that you can change `sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)` => `sts = p.wait()`

Comment: also try with `shell=True`. It's ugly, but it emulates the shell better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jean-Francois Fabre got me on the right track:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('scp username@hostname:/dir/to/files/\{a,b,c\} /target/dir',
shell=True)
sts = p.wait()
```

The

```
shell=True
```

argument was the missing bit. It is a solution that is not [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations), but at least it's working.

Comment: Braces are intended to shorten interactive use. You are typing this into a text editor, so you have easy access to copy-and-paste; just pass the three file names separately rather than unnecessarily using the shell to expand the brace expression.

Comment: If you are using `shell=True`, there is no need for the list; the first argument should just be the single string in the list.

Answer (score 4):

cannot test, but I would remove all blackslashes altogether since they're just here to protect the expansion from the shell on the local machine:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['scp', 'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/{a,b,c}',
                      '/target/dir'])
sts = p.wait()
```

also note that `p.wait()` is way better than the wait command you performed (more portable!)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a shell feature unnecessarily in a script; you have your text editor to make typing easier. Just pass the three file names individually:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['scp',
                      'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/a',
                      'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/b',
                      'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/c',
                      '/target/dir'])
```

Alternatively, let *Python* build the list of files for you.

```
file_list = ['username@hostname:/dir/to/files/%s' % (s,)
             for f in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
p = subprocess.Popen(['scp'] + file_list + ['/target/dir'])
```

Comment: This would be very cumbersome, as I would have to enter a password for each file and in general the number of files is greater than 3.

Comment: Then just use Jean-Francois Fabre's answer, as *locally* there is nothing special about the braces. Or even better, set up public-key authentication so that you don't need to type a password any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it correctly, you need to have the "\" and the "{". Since you need to escape both of them, what about `'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/\\\{a,b,c\\\}'`

Comment: Isn't `'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/\\\{a,b,c\\\}' == r'username@hostname:/dir/to/files/\\{a,b,c\\}'`?